Her erogenous zone killed her
Okay I had only caught a snippet of this movie and it intrigued me as well as gave me the heebie~geebies. I can't remember the premise but a female had part of her skull removed and her brain was exposed. She was having a conversation with a male character. Now this whole time as she is talking she is rubbing her fingers back and forth across her gray matter. No one says anything to her about this. She wants to stop but can't because it's stimulating her pleasure spot. She ended up rubbing herself to death. It left me twisting 'cause if I were to be in that spot would I do the same? Enjoying it too much to stop but knowing how gross and disgusting it was? And do you think you would slip 'n slide yourself to death or would you be able to refrain from doing so? Anyhow... I'd like to know the title of said movie and some backstory if possible. Thanx everyone! Have an awesome day.

Welcome to the community. Any other plot details? If you know, please also describe the genre, language, country and year of production, plot locale, descriptions of actors, color or BW, etc. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Thank you, John. I will try to follow your guidelines if I can. I was going to ask a question but I will see if I can find it before asking. Just wanted to say Thanx...

Dead End (2003)

Christmas Eve. On his way to his in-laws with his family, Frank Harrington decides to try a shortcut, for the first time in 20 years. It turns out to be the biggest mistake of his life.

I can't find a YouTube with the scene in it, but this seems to be the most plausible movie based on a similar question from Yahoo Answers (UK).

Hi, Ron. Thank you so much for your response. Yeah I seen that YouTube has taken this movie down. So I guess I'll do some more research to hopefully locate this specific scene. But you have gotten me so much closer. Thank You again. Have an awesome day!
